# Barut-Zanghi (BZ) Lagrangian derivation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, dirac-equation, constrained-dynamics, classical-field-theory

I'm trying to derive the BZ Lagrangian (density) from the Dirac Hamiltonian density and some questions popped up.
BZ Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{i}{2}(\dot{\bar{\psi}}\psi - \bar{\psi}\dot{\psi}) + p_\mu(\dot{x}^\mu - \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi)\tag{1}$$
where the four-potential $A_\mu$ is set to zero for simplicity.
The first question is: how can I derive it? As it can be seen, the first right member is  the time derivative inside the Dirac Lagrangian (which corresponds to the conjugate momenta) and if I set $p_\mu\gamma^\mu = m$, then second member in brackets is the second term of Dirac Lagrangian.
I though that it can be derived from the Legendre transform starting with the Dirac Hamiltonian and the conjugate momenta (that I know) and inserting the other conjugate momenta linked to the dynamical variables $(x_\mu, p_\mu)$, i.e. $p_\mu\dot{x}^\mu$ .
The problem is that there's the divergence term of the Dirac Hamiltonian that doesn't appear. Any advice?
The second question is the following: I saw that the Lagrangian density depends on fields and their derivatives: in this case we have $\psi$,$\bar{\psi}$ as fields and their derivative there aren't. Although, in this case we also have a dependence from the dynamical variables $(x_\mu, p_\mu)$. How can I justify this?

Answer (score 0):

1. The [Barut-Zanghi (BZ) Lagrangian](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.52.2009)
   $$\begin{align} L ~=~& \frac{i}{2}(\dot{\bar{\psi}}\psi - \bar{\psi}\dot{\psi}) + p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu} \cr &-(p_{\mu}-qA_{\mu}) \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi, \cr \bar{\psi} ~=~&\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^0 ,\end{align}\tag{1} $$
   is a point-mechanical (rather than a field-theoretic) model, i.e. all the variables depend only on time. In contrast the spinor in the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) is a field.
2. The BZ Hamiltonian
   $$H~=~ (p_{\mu}-qA_{\mu}) \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi\tag{2}$$ is minus the terms without time derivatives in the BZ Lagrangian (1), cf. e.g. the [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075).

Comment: This seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9607212

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly thought that was CFT. Anyways, from where can I start deriving this Lagrangian? Because I’m assuming that only the Dirac Hamiltonian is known.

Comment: Perhaps this is explained/motivated in the original BZ paper?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not explained anywhere